Unresolved reference 'pip' в PyCharm
Хотел поставить в PyCharm пакет bokeh для визуализации данных.
На сайте инструкция по установке:
pip install bokeh
Но когда пишу это в файле в PyCharm вылезает даже несколько ошибок:\

Unresolved reference 'pip'
End of statement expected
Unresolved reference 'install'
End of statement expected
Unresolved reference 'bokeh'

Что с pip? Почему он не работает? Версия питона 3.12.3.

В каком файле вы это пишете? Это нужно писать в терминале. И ещё нужно иметь хотя бы общее понятие об окружениях питона, потому что дальше у вас будет вопрос: "я поставил библиотеку, а мой скрипт её не видит".


Вам нужно убедиться, что вы правильно импортировали необходимые пакеты в вашем проекте.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.
